Can't save file in Spring Boot
.yml
file:
  upload-dir: src/main/resources/static/profileIMG

Controller
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("profile_img_path") MultipartFile file,
                                                   @RequestParam("id") String id,
                                                   @RequestParam("password") String password,
                                                   @RequestParam("name") String name,
                                                   @RequestParam("nickname") String nickname,
                                                   @RequestParam("age") int age,
                                                   @RequestParam("gender") String gender,
                                                   @RequestParam("tel") String tel) {

        MemberDTO memberDTO = new MemberDTO();
        memberDTO.setId(id);
        memberDTO.setPwd(password);
        memberDTO.setName(name);
        memberDTO.setNickname(nickname);
        memberDTO.setAge(age);
        memberDTO.setGender(gender);
        memberDTO.setTel(tel);

        // 파일이 비어있는지 확인
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("파일을 선택해 주세요");
        }

        try {
            // 절대 경로 설정
            Path currentPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")).toAbsolutePath();
            Path uploadPath = currentPath.resolve("src/main/resources/static").resolve(uploadDir);
            if (!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
                Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
            }

            // 고유한 파일명 생성
            String uniqueFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8) + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
            Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(uniqueFileName);

            // 디버깅을 위한 경로 출력
            System.out.println("파일 저장 경로: " + filePath.toString());

            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), filePath);

            // 파일명을 MemberDTO에 설정
            memberDTO.setProfileIMG(uniqueFileName);

            // 회원 정보와 파일 이름을 데이터베이스에 저장
            memberService.insertMember(memberDTO);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("파일 업로드 실패");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("회원 가입 완료");
    }

DB is saved and the path output becomes normal. And it prints out that the save was successful.
But the file is not saved.
What's the problem?
I'm a talking potato :(
I don't know what to touch.
I would appreciate it if you wrote it in an easy-to-understand way.
I am a beginner.


There is no src/main/resources as in the end that is the root of the classpath. 2. you cannot write to the root of the classpath because that would be inside of a jar/war file which you cannot modify.


U R so smart! thx for U
I solved the problem. XD
